# Not able to connect to Amazon Redshift Cluster from Aginity

Tags: amazon-redshift, aginity

I am trying to connect to Redshift cluster ( available ) from Aginity workbench for Redshift. I plugged in all the required credentials which are used in creating the cluster but still I get the below error. Can someone help me with this. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Is the Redshift cluster publicly accessible? Is the security group open?

Comment: No, it is not publicly accessible.

Comment: Where are you trying to run Aginity from? A Windows server on AWS in your VPC? Or on you local computer?

Comment: I have aginity for redshift installed on windows 7( my local computer )

Comment: Then you will need to enable the "publicly accessible" flag on the Redshift cluster. As it is only resources inside your VPC can access the cluster right now. Also you will need to add your local IP address to the security group assigned to the Redshift cluster.

Comment: There are bunch of Elastic IPs in the drop down. Which one do I need to select from them?

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. How are Elastic IPs related to this at all? Are you talking about the IP address you should enter in the security group? That should be your local computer's IP address, not an Elastic IP.

Comment: In Configure Networking options there is an option called Choose a Public IP address where  yes or no needs to be selected. If I select yes then its asking me to pick a Elastic IP from a bunch of IPs in the drop down.

Comment: You can't assign Elastic IPs to Redshift, unless they just released that feature today without announcing it. So I have no clue what you are talking about.

Comment: can you access your redshift cluster from elsewhere or from another product/tool?

Comment: No.. still no luck :(

Comment: @Mark B - I'm having the same issue as Teja.  I have set the database as Publicly Accessible.  How do I "add (my) local IP address to the security group assigned to the Redshift cluster" ? (Or alternatively, how do I run Aginity from a 'Windows server on AWS in your VPC"?